# Laravel: Adding log channels outside logging.php configuration (plugin development)

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.8, monolog

I'm working on a laravel plugin/package.
We want to define our own loggers outside of the main project configuration (`config/logger.php`)

I have tried the following in the ServiceProvider `register()` function.

Based on the MonoLogger test code.

```
$partLogger = new Logger('vendor_part-log');
$partLogHandler = new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/vendor/part-log.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$partLogger->pushHandler($partLogHandler);
// MonoLog Registry
Registry::addLogger($partLogger, 'vendor_part-log');
```

Sadly this doesn't work inside Laravel.
I also can't get the other existing loggers from `Registry::`

So the problem is that the new channel won't register.

Is there a different Registry in use inside Laravel or do I need an entirely different solution to achieve this?

Comment: can you tell us what is the issue exactly or error you are getting?

Comment: No errors, I simply can't get the new log channel to register.

Comment: @HTDutchy i think `Registry::addLogger($partLogger, 'vendor_part-log');` line is not needed.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya If it wasnt needed it would already work. the Logger is a new instance, nothing existing it will magically hook to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we'd still like a more automated solution, we've compromised and are using a static function as source of the configuration.

In `config/logging.php`:

At the top replace `return [...` with `$config = [...`.

And at the bottom add the following lines:

```
$config['channels'] = array_merge(
    $config['channels'],
    \FooVendor\Bar\Classes\Logs::getLogs(),
);

return $config;
```

And create the mentioned class with the following function:

```
    /**
     * Configs to be merged in config/logging.php
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getLogs()
    {
        return [
            'foo_partlogger' => [
                'driver' => 'single',
                'path' => storage_path('logs/foo/partlogger.log'),
                'level' => 'debug',
            ],
            'foo_second_partlogger' => [
                'driver' => 'single',
                'path' => storage_path('logs/foo/second_partlogger.log'),
                'level' => 'debug',
            ],
        ];
    }
```